# Append HTML in the polymer

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, iron

Here is my html

```html
<div id="setImgWrap">
<!-- Here append image will be show -->
</div>
```

and here i am appending  from js

```js
this.addedImages =  {
 imageURL : self.downloadURL  
};
this.$.setImgWrap.append('<iron-image src="' +[[this.addedImages.imageURL]] + '"></iron-image>');
```

I want to show all uploaded image on browser, but this is showing whole  tag in side the double quotes. How to i can show multiple images ?

Comment: Try this `<iron-image src="[[' +this.addedImages.imageURL]+ ']]"></iron-image>`

Comment: I i tried its now working , have to use quotes inside the append(). otherwise its showing error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

The format of one-way binding in polymer is `[[varibale]]`. But when you do like

```
<iron-image src="' +[[this.addedImages.imageURL]] + '"></iron-image>
```

that will be evaluated as there is no variable `[[this.addedImages.imageURL]]` of course it won't be a variable.

So, you must do this

```
<iron-image src="[[' +this.addedImages.imageURL+ ']]"></iron-image>
```

then the variable will be evaluated to image path i.e., `"[[' +this.addedImages.imageURL+ ']]"` will be changed to "`[[this.addedImages.imageURL]]"`

check [Data binding in polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#property-binding) for more info

```
append('<iron-image src="[[\' +this.addedImages.imageURL+ \']]"></iron-image>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i want to append whole <iron-image> tag from js to html.

Comment: Just mention the same in `append`. There is difference right.

Comment: I used it like that - this.$.setImgWrap.append('<iron-image src="[[' +this.addedImages.imageURL]+ ']]"></iron-image>'); but instead of showing image its showing whole "<iron-image>" tag in double quotes at browser.

Comment: you are ending a bracket after imageURL , so where is the opening of this bracket ?